# Prove $Aut(\Bbb Z_{p}^d)$ is isomorphic to $GL(d,p)$

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, finite-fields

Sorry for the poor notations, but I'd greatly appreciate any comments/suggestions for my proof written below.

We know for a fact that $\Bbb Z_{p}^d$ is a vector space of dimension $d$ over the field $GF(p)$, and
$$GL(d,p)=\{\text{invertible }d\times d\text{ matrices over the field } GF(p)\}$$

On the other hand $$Aut(\Bbb Z_{p}^d) = \{\text{bijective homomorphisms from }\Bbb Z_p^d\text{ to itself}\} = \{\text{linear transformations }T :\Bbb Z_p^d \to \Bbb Z_p^d \text{ such that $T$ is invertible}\}$$

Therefore $Aut(\Bbb Z_{p}^d)$ is isomorphic to $GL(d,p)$.

How can I construct a more rigorous proof for this lemma?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two groups here.

There is $G_1$, say: the automorphisms of the abelian  group $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^d$.

There is $G_2$, say: the automorphisms of the $\mathbb{Z}_p$-vector space $(\mathbb{Z}_p)^d$, isomorphic of course to the matrix group $\text{GL}(d,p)$ via a choice of basis.

Now obviously every element of $G_2$ is an element of $G_1$; just forget the scalar multiplication, it still preserves the group addition.

But the converse is true. Given an element $\alpha$ of $G_1$, it preserves all the additive group structure, but it also preserves the scalar multiplication, since 
$$
\alpha(r\cdot v)=\alpha(v+\dots+v)=\alpha(v)+\dots+\alpha(v)=r\cdot\alpha(v)
$$
where the $\dots$ mean a sum with $r$ terms.

So $G_1=G_2$.

Comment: Here $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field iff $p$ is prime. Otherwise $\mathbb{Z}_p^d$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module, and the same matrix theory applies as for vector spaces, invertible matrices being those with [invertible determinant in $\mathbb{Z}_d$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix#Definition) (non-trivial)

Comment: In the question as set $p$ is prime; "the field $\text{GF}(p)$.

Comment: well I wanted to mention the adjugate matrix

Comment: There is one last thing I want to ask: how can I rigorously justify G2 is isomorphic to GL(p,d)?

Comment: Every choice of basis associates each linear transformation with its matrix wrt that basis; this association is a homomorphism (need to check the matrix of $ST$ is the product of the matrices of $S$ and $T$; it carries invertible transformations to non-singular matrices; it is 1--1 and it is onto. These are all a bit tedious to prove but not difficult.